# Dose not work laravel sub_domain On centos 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, subdomain, centos7

I have Laravel project and I have route like this

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.mydomain.com'), function () {
   Route::get('/test', ['uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TetsController@index',   
       function ($account) {
      return view('Test');
  }]);
}]);
```

It works on localhost (windows,wamp) but when I migrate on centos It does not work and send me this error

> This site can’t be reached
>
> test.mydomain.com’s server DNS address could not be found. Search
>   Google for test support ir login ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: No , It dose not exist. but on windows it works correctly

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel (nor CentOS). Just your DNS records.

Answer (score 0):

I use cloudflare on my host and I add `*` in DNS section and work Correctly.